# I am learning MPI programming and got struck with MPI_Isend And MPI_Irecv

Tags: c, mpi

I want to run a program to understand how MPI_Isend  and MPI_Irecv works. Isend and Irecv for rank 0 is working properly but Irecv in rank 5 is taking default values. can someone explains me this?

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<mpi.h>  
#include<stdlib.h>  
#include<string.h>  
int main(int argc , char *argv[])  
  {
    int rank;
    int size;
    int i;
    int index;
    int ph_number[10] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int recv_numb[10];
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Request request;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    if(rank ==0)
    {

        MPI_Isend(&ph_number,8,MPI_INT,0,10,MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
        MPI_Isend(&ph_number,8,MPI_INT,5,11,MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
        MPI_Irecv(&recv_numb,9,MPI_INT,0,10,MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);

        printf("recv number[7] = %d \n \n ", recv_numb[7]);
    }

        if(rank==5)
        {

            MPI_Irecv(&recv_numb,9,MPI_INT,0,11,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request);
            printf("recv number[5] = %d in rank %d\n \n ",recv_numb[5],rank);
        }

        MPI_Finalize();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MPI_Wait(&request, &status);
```

The point is that ranks > 1 are receiving in non-blocking mode and you miss data. You have to check return value of *MPI_Irecv*, or call *MPI_Wait* after receiving (but it is useless, because you can simply use blocking *MPI_Recv*).

```
rank 0 Isend() --                    rank x Irecv()
                 \----                      printf()
                      \-------------> //data are received now, but output is already printed
```